# Spill CSS Div over into a neighboring container (WordPress authoring)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to replicate the look on the following website: http://lousrestaurant.net/

You'll see that bottom part of the logo spills onto the menu bar (a separate div in WP). The header logo, and menu bar are all one image. WP generates the menu text formatting, so only have to worry about the background image.

I've Photoshopped my own header image with the menu bar (solid band) at the bottom of the header image, but cannot get it to spill onto the nav bar div.

Using this, I've partially succeeded:

```
#branding img
{
clear: both;
display: block;
background-image:url('myimage.png');
background-size: 940px 185px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
}
```

It's quirky though, for two reasons:

1. The main page container's position then needs to be set, due to the `position:absolute` above it.
2. Some browsers think there is no header image since I insert the above CSS into the `style.css`, and don't use WP's "very helpful" header image uploader.

I've had many years of HTML and CSS experience, but I'm rather new to WordPress and am getting hung up there I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their code it's basically

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="/"></a>
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

they're applying the background image to the `#header` then making the `a` take up that space to be clickable, so they're not spilling out of the div, the image is a background of the wrapping element. It looks like you're adding an element to overflow it, when there is no need to overflow if you go up a level in the hierarchy.

Comment: Interesting. I'll play with adding the background image to the #header, not #header img. The a href simply makes the image clickable back to the home page. I'll let you know!

Comment: No workie. #header puts img on header in FF, but Chrome, IE think there is no header; they show the img but Chrome has the grey box and IE has the X indicting "we think there is an empty image container." Lastly, the header image does not spill over onto the menu. I set the #access (nav) to "transparent" background, but no go, unless I use Position Absolute, and then works, but still Chrome and IE are not happy.

Comment: are you setting height & width on the elements? use firebug or chrome dev tool to see what code they used and emulate that...

Comment: Yes, using Firebug. Have spent hours. No sweat adding the header image, adding postion, etc. But now cannot get Chrome IE (they should outlaw IE) to understand there is an image in there. I'm using WP's Weaver theme, which has plenty of highly functional quick options, but I've also downloaded the style.css and edited manually. Something with the theme maybe...

Comment: Tweaked a little more. Displaying in FF fine, Chrome, IE still "think" there is no header image, yet one is positioned correctly, transparent through navbar, but still IE has the little red "X" showing in the top left of the header container.

Comment: I've got it pretty much. At the end of the style.css there is another #header, under the print CSS. Working in Chrome with Firebug, if I take out that div, then all gtg, but of course, if anyone wanted to print the web page, oops! So now wondering if I need to be redundant with my header background url image?

Comment: Generally not a good idea to have background images in the print stylesheet, if it's using the `@media print` thing it shouldn't be picked up by `screen`

Comment: I somewhat solved the issue. I formatted the header image in css, then created an exact size header image, that fit the exact size of the masthead container, and uploaded via WordPress' header upload utility. This seems to have satisfied the javascript uploader that, otherwise, would crop the bottom of my file. I don't think this is the best fix, but works for now.